# Загрузка image в pdf (xhtml2pdf)

Tags: python, django

ситуация в следующем, я пытаюсь создать pdf файл в котором будет логотип. Однако при конвертации html (в котором рендериться логотип) в pdf картинка не передается.
Пытался вывести картинку как `<img>` как `background-image`.

как сделать так, что бы в пдф файл передавалась картинка?

мой код utils

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import os

def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != 0:
        path = r'  <my path to fonts>  '
    else:
        path = None
    print(path)
    return path

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result, encoding='utf-8', link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)

    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

моя view.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.template.loader import get_template
from .utils import render_to_pdf 
import codecs

class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('pdf_gen.html')
        with codecs.open('./templates/pdf_gen.html', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            html = f.read() 
        context = {
            "customer_name": "John cooper",
            "amount": 123231,
            "today": "Today",
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        # return    HttpResponse(html)

        # html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_gen.html' , context)

        if html:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/force-download')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("213231231")
            content = "inline; filename = %s" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return  HttpResponse("Not found")
```

мой html

```
<body>
    <div class = "qwe">
            <img src="{% static 'image/logo_pdf.jpg' %}" width="175px" height="75px"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Так у вас `fetch_pdf_resources` всегда возвращает только жёстко прописанный путь к шрифту, даже если рендеру требуется картинка.

Comment: проблема в том, что изначальный код добавлял точку в пути к файлу. http://localhost/static/.css/style.css

перед папкой css почему-то вставляло точку и не находило не шрифт не картинку

Comment: Правильным решением этой проблемы является выяснение того, почему `fetch_pdf_resources` возвращает неправильный путь, а не прописывание пути руками.

Comment: файл подключился но выдаёт ошибку 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 16: invalid continuation byte